# Placing images with Tkinter and Pillow

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm building a blackjack gui game and I need help orienting the cards. I've thinking of using frames because I'm more familiar with frames, but I have a feeling using a grid might be better.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def hit():
    print("hit was pressed")

def stand():
    print("stand was pressed")

def new_hand():
    print("new hand was pressed")

'''
Creates the window
'''
window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Black Jack")
window.geometry("800x600")
window.configure(bg="#0C8702")

'''
Pulls one image and displays it to the screen
    - Will need to fix and update
'''
# image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("PNG/2C.png"), size="10x10")
# panel1 = tk.Label(window, image=image1)
# panel1.pack(side="left")
image1 = Image.open("PNG/2C.png")
resize_img1 = image1.resize((50, 100))
real_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_img1)
panel1 = tk.Label(image=real_img)
panel1.image = real_img
panel1.pack()

'''
Creates the bottom buttons
    - Hit
    - Stand
    - New Hand
    - Quit
'''
buttons = ttk.Frame(window, padding=(20,10,20,0))
buttons.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")

hit_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="Hit", command=hit)
hit_button.pack(side="left",fill="x")
# hit_button.place(x=0, y=575)

stand_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="Stand", command=stand)
stand_button.pack(side="left",fill="x")
# stand_button.place(x=100, y=575)
# hit_button.pack(side="left")

deal_new_hand_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="New Hand", command=new_hand)
deal_new_hand_button.pack(side="left", fill="x")

quit_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="Quit", command=window.destroy)
quit_button.pack(side="left", fill="x")

window.mainloop()
```

[image: Window output]

I've updated my code to display an image, but I'm getting a blank image. It's at the very top of the page. Right now, I'd like to be able to display the actual image and then I'd like those images to appear where those red boxes are.

I opened the image and created a label for it, but nothing shows up. The image is supposed to be a 2 of clubs.

I have the images in a folder called PNG which is in the same location as this file.

Comment: I've run your code using my own image and it works fine, on Windows 10.

Comment: I tried it again with a different image. I tried both jpeg and a different png file and it worked. Why is that? Why doesn't this work with my other images? Is there something wrong with the images i've chosen? They are all png so i'm don't understand why this doesn't work

Comment: I suggest you use your favorite image editor and check them out.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work by running it on python 3.9. I appreciate the help. Why is it that that particular image wasn't working on python 3.8, but just about every other image i tried (jpeg and png) worked. Why did python 3.9 fix that issue? This issue was only occurring with my set of card images, but worked just fine with other images and i don't see why python 3.9 would fix it. I read through some of the update changes and i dont see why this update somehow fixed this issue.

Comment: At least you got it working!